# convert negative seconds into hh:mm:ss format

Tags: php

I want to have a function that converts positive and negative seconds in Timeformat h:i:s

So I have value like

```
$seconds= -41880;
```

Try with first function

```
 function secToHR($seconds) 
        {
        $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
        $mins = floor($seconds / 60 % 60);
        $secs = floor($seconds % 60);
        $time = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
     
        return $time;
                    
        }
```

result is

```
$time = -12:-38:00
```

When I use a positive value for $seconds

```
$seconds = 100380
```

then result is like

```
$time =     27:53:00
```

what is correct

Then second function

```
function secToHR2($seconds)
    {
    $time    = gmdate("h:i:s", abs($seconds));
    if ($seconds < 0) {
    $time = '-' . $time;
    }
    return $time;
    }
```

for
$seconds= -41880

result

```
 $time =    -11:38:00
```

which is correct

but for

```
$seconds = 100380
```

result is now

```
$time : 03:53:00
```

which is now wrong

Does someone have the clue which functions I need and modified so that it is working correct for positive and negative values

Comment: [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) (and the other [date-time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) as well) represents the number of seconds passed as argument as a date, not as a number of hours, minutes and seconds. It never returns a value greater than 23 for `h` and so on. Combine the logic of the two functions: use the code of `secToHR()` to format the absolute value of its argument and the logic of `secToHR2()` to handle the sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) (and the other [date-time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) as well) represents the number of seconds passed as argument as a date, not as a number of hours, minutes and seconds. It never returns a value greater than 23 for `h` and so on.

Combine the logic of the two functions: use the code of `secToHR()` to format the absolute value of its argument and the logic of `secToHR2()` to handle the sign.

```
function secToHR($seconds) 
{
    // Separate the sign and the absolute value of $seconds
    $sign = '';
    if ($seconds < 0) {
        $sign    = '-';
        $seconds = -$seconds;
    }

    // Compute the components
    $secs = $seconds % 60;
    $minutes = ($seconds - $secs) / 60;
    $mins = $minutes % 60;
    $hours = ($minutes - $mins) / 60;

    // P
    return sprintf('%s%02d:%02d:%02d', $sign, $hours, $mins, $secs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to

1. extract any negative sign
2. call your function that's only defined for positive values (`secToHR`)
3. reinsert the negative sign if appropriate